# Using Selenium Builder plugin to handle iframes

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, selenium-builder

I am using the selenium builder plugin in firefox.

I was executing events on a website and saw that selenium builder wasnt able to record them.

After looking into it I found out that the website used **iframe**. I know I can go and add *switchToFrame* in the builder but is there any way the builder could detect **iframes** automatically while recording?

Comment: Yeah, you would think that the creator of SeleniumBuilder could detect a browser window onfocus event and then translate that into a switchTo method in the builder script.  Not sure the reason why it doesn't already support that.

Answer (score 0):

if you export your test to java you can use

```
driver.switchTo().frame()
```

to get the context of an iframe.

br paul